# Selenium-WebDriver: New windows do not inherit proxy settings when using ie.usePerProcessProxy

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to emulate clicking in my application and capturing all the web traffic from the opened page using a proxy. I am using Webdriver and IE 8. The initial page works fine but the new page's traffic is not captured correctly. Seems like the below issue might be the reason. Does anyone know if this was fixed or if there is a known workaround for this issue?

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8112

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy workaround for the issue. Any workaround would require creating a [Windows hook procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which could hook the message loop of the newly opened browser window and call the appropriate [WinINet API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the proxy for that window, which is running in a new process. As it happens, a fix for the issue you referenced has been in progress for some time now, and was [committed just recently](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=c269a8315b158ed628e75bf22a6c40239e717c07), and it should be available in the next full release of the Selenium project.

Having said that, the general response to questions about the issue being fixed is that the IE driver development team for the Selenium project is pretty rigorous about updating issues with comments when updates to the issue are warranted. In the unlikely event the issue report itself is not updated when an issue is fixed, the [IE driver change log](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG) contains descriptions of the updates to every commit to the IE driver. Asking, "Is it fixed yet," or, "Are there any updates," either in an issue's comments, or on one of the project mailing lists, or in any other forum is likely to be ignored. In the case of the IE driver portion of Selenium project, if there hasn't been a comment added to the issue report, then no, there are no updates on the issue. Furthermore, adding the comment is unlikely in the extreme to "bump" the priority to get it looked at any faster.

Full disclosure: This writer is a member of the development team for the IE driver for the Selenium project.

Comment: Jim, thanks for providing a fix for this issue. In our application we are using Web Driver to launch multiple browsers (IE 8) which are connecting to their own proxies (Mina). The proxies are recording the traffic from these browsers. While opening the initial page the proxies are fine but when a click is initiated and a new browser window is opened the web traffic is mixed up between the proxies. The newest browser window uses the proxy of the last opened browser. Could you please point me in the right direction to handle the scenario? We are blocked on this.

Comment: StackOverflow really isn't the place for a back-and-forth exploration of things like this. In particular, comments make for a poor exploration of what is actually another question. Nevertheless, running parallel instances of IE with the per-process proxy setting could be unpredictable. With the advent of loosely-coupled IE, window handles might be reused by IE, which might cause unpredictability in which window (and which proxy instance) is getting used by the browser. It's not something the driver can control, and the implementation of per-process proxy settings are a hack in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be fixed in latest version.

From Change Log File : Fixed passing per-process proxy settings to new windows. Fixes issue #8112

Please check [Selenium Change Log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG) for more details